# How can I add make faces read-only?

Tags: org-mode, faces

I want to make specific faces read-only.

For example, I want to make all `org-mode` headlines and drawers to be read only (among other things)

Pieces of the puzzle I've looked into:

- Preventing deletion of hidden text
- the text property `read-only`
- there are overlays that can be used to apply properties to regions
- I don't think there's a face attribute for `read-only` from what I saw in `customize`

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info

Comment: The question is unclear. Do you mean make all text that is highlighted with a certain face read-only? You say you want to make a **face** read-only -- what do you mean by that?